# Returning allValues from dictionary sorted by initial placement

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsdictionary, nsnumber

Then I perform allValues I have array of strings, but they sorted alphabetically. How can I get array of objects sorted by their placement order ?

Second question: how can I sort this objects for keys? Keys are NSNumbers from zero to 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries and in particular NSDictionary is an unordered collection. There is not order, the order of initially entries is not maintained.

If you want an order you will have to arrange that yourself. Perhaps a parallel array or an order entry in the dictionary items, or perhaps an array is the best container or ....